# Is continuity preserved under Max operator and Euclidean norm?

Tags: continuity, convex-analysis

Suppose that the functions $f_i: \mathbb{R}^k \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are all continuous over $\mathbb{R}^k$ for $i=1,...,k$. Is the function
$$
g(x)=\|\max\{0,f_1(x)\},...,\max\{0,f_k(x)\}\|^2
$$
continuous over $\mathbb{R}^k$?

Comment: Why is the norm taken, because the max will already be positive right?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I have edited the question because there were mistakes.

Comment: The composition of ocntinuous functions is continuous.